# How to extract RGB arguments as a list

Tags: color

Although the following lines of code work fine they are very awkward.

My questions are below

```
a = RGBColor[1, 0, 0]
b = RGBColor[0, 1, 0]
```

Is there a more compact way to construct ab?

Can the three entries of `RGBColor[u,v,w]` be extracted as a list?

Can the RGBColor argument be entered as a list RGB[{list}]?

```
ab = RGBColor[a[[1]] + b[[1]], a[[2]] + b[[2]], a[[3]] + b[[3]]]
Graphics[{{a, Disk[{0, .5}, .5]}, {b, Disk[{.25, .5}, .5]}, {ab, 
   Disk[{.5, .5}, .5]}}]
```

Comment: Try `RGBColor[u,v,w] /. RGBColor->List`.

Comment: This `RGBColor[{r,g,b}]` works. In general `f@@{1,2,3}` is equivalent to `f[1,2,3]`.

Comment: Converting between RGBColor and List can be done in both directions with `@@`. If you want to convert several of them in a list, you can use `@@@`. For example: `ab = RGBColor@@Total[List@@@{a,b}]`. However note that for the most common colour calculations there already exist `Blend`, `Lighter` and `Darker`.

Answer (score 10):

Just use [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) (short form `@@`):

```
RGBColor @@ {1, 0, 0}
```

> ```
> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]
> ```

```
List @@ RGBColor[1, 0, 0]
```

> ```
> {1, 0, 0}
> ```

See:  [Applying Functions to Lists and Other Expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ApplyingFunctionsToListsAndOtherExpressions.html)

---

Okay, I actually missed the crux of your question because of the lack of [formatting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) in the original.

You could get `ab` using `Thread[a + b, RGBColor]` -- see [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to add a formatted worksheet to a question. Sorry about the formatting.  The built in functions like Blend do not combine. RGDColor(1,0,0) and. RGB(0.1.0) to. RGB(1,1,0).   Using the above lists this is straightforward.    THANKS TO ALL

Answer (score 1):

To make all the assignments on one line:

```
colors = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
{black, red, green, blue} = RGB @@@ colors

red => RGB[1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: `RGBColor` rather than `RGB`?